# Stored procedure not returning data inexpected format

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that does exactly what I want, but the presentation is not what I  expected, or what I want it to be. This is the code:

```
DECLARE @debitos TABLE (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(100), col4 varchar(100), col5 varchar(100), col6 varchar(100));

 --Insert the debitos that met the criteria

INSERT INTO @debitos
select no, nome, nrdoc, (CONCAT(CONVERT (money, edeb), ' €')), (FORMAT (dataven, 'dd-MM-yy')), (DATEDIFF(d,dataven,getdate())) from cc
where ultdoc not like '%recibo%' and cmdesc like '%N/Factura%' and (DATEADD(day, 0, GETDATE()) - dataven > 30) and deb > 0 and datalc > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
order by dataven asc

 --Create a row check to determine whether to send the email or not

DECLARE @rows int;
SET @rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @debitos)

 --Set the body elements

DECLARE @message varchar(1000);
-- declare the xml data to pass to the HTML body
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- body will hold the HTML formatted table in the email
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX);

 --Create the columns that will hold each row of data as xml

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT col1 AS 'td','',col2 AS 'td','', col3 AS 'td','', col4 AS 'td', col5 AS 'td', col6 AS 'td'
FROM @debitos
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

 --Set the HTML for the body

SET @body ='<html><body><H3> * FACTURAS VENCIDAS HÁ MAIS DE 30 DIAS * </H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> N. Cliente </th> <th> Cliente </th> <th> N. Factura </th> <th> Valor </th> <th> Data de Venc. </th> <th> Dias Venc. </th> </tr>'

 --Stitch everything together, appending the HTML table

SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

SET NOCOUNT ON 

 --Check if any debitos met the criteria

IF @rows > 0 
BEGIN

 --Send the email and append the data table to the body

EXEC dbo.uspSendEmail 'Débitos de Clientes', 'mail@carro.ts', @body, NULL, 'mail@carro.ts','mail@carro.ts'
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

I have a job scheduling the delivery of the results, but the last two column values appear inside the 4th column, with the data all scrambled, something like this:

**686.43 €02-10-20109**

What am I doing wrong, can anyone give a help?

Comment: Ww can't run your SQL, so we can't replicate the problem. Take the time to give us a [mre] with your expected results as well.

Comment: Though, at a guess, it's because you "forgot" to put `,''` after columns `col4`, `col5`, and `col6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete stab in the dark, but I noticed that you didn't have `,''` after some of your columns in the `FOR XML PATH` section, meaning that the nodes would be combined into one. Using line breaks,and white space would really help you spot what are more or less typographic errors (as they are simple oversights). What you have is:

```sql
SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT col1 AS 'td','',col2 AS 'td','', col3 AS 'td','', col4 AS 'td', col5 AS 'td', col6 AS 'td'
FROM @debitos
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

But it should be the following (with added formatting for readability):

```sql
SET @xml = CAST((SELECT col1 AS td, '',
                        col2 AS td, '',
                        col3 AS td, '',
                        col4 AS td, '',
                        col5 AS td, '',
                        col6 AS td, ''
                 FROM @debitos
                 FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS) AS nvarchar(MAX));
```

Comment: you are my guardian angels, thank you very much, it was the apostrophe that was missing. thanks mates!